# Struggling to put function into table. "Missing '(' near new."

Tags: lua, love2d

I have this code right here, in a file named "hframe.lua".

```lua
table.insert(handler.class, framename)
local func = [[
function new(())
print("Hello Stackoverflow!")
end
]] --The function test itself.
local a="table.insert(handler.class."..framename..", "..func..")" --I broke it in two to make things easier for me to read.
print(a) --Read out the variable so I can see what it looks like.
local b=load(a) --Load it up
b() --Nil error. Great.
```

"framename" is a constant from another file, which is simply declared as "frame". The error is a simple nil error. Upon running b(), it throws a local nil error. With an assert, I've discovered this error.

```
Error: Thread error (Thread: 0x04c7d2f0)

uicode/hframe.lua:16: [string "table.insert(handler.class.frame, function ne..."]:1: '(' expected near 'new'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'assert'
        uicode/hframe.lua:16: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        uicode/handlerthread.lua:165: in main chunk
stack traceback:
        [string "boot.lua"]:777: in function <[string "boot.lua"]:773>
        [C]: in function 'error'
        [string "boot.lua"]:631: in function <[string "boot.lua"]:630>
        [string "boot.lua"]:604: in function <[string "boot.lua"]:594>
        [C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

I'm not entirely sure WHY it's throwing this error, because clearly I define it as function new(). What I have I done wrong?

Comment: I'm curious why did you choose to use `load` here? did you want to test how it works? or what is your actual problem? because as is this code doesn't make too much sense to me. also you're inserting framename into handler.class but you use handler.class[framename].

Comment: @Piglet:I'm doing some REALLY experimental stuff, so load() was there to test how it all worked. Also, table.insert is a new thing to me, since I've not used to table manipulation. I was hoping to create something that could resemble a call like handler.class.frame.new(which is something I am used to and know how to define without table.insert.) The load() is because I wasn't aware there was a way for me to properly insert a multi-line table insert at the time I was originally designing it, and then just kept with the load command because I knew it'd work if done right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function new() end
```

is syntactic sugar for

```
new = function () end
```

This is an assignment. It does not resolve to a value. Hence you cannot use a function definiton where a value is expected.

In your case the code executed is

```
table.insert(handler.class.someFrameName,
  function new () print("Hello Stackoverflow!") end
)
```

The only thing that would make sense for Lua with the function keyword present in a list of expressions is an anonymous function and it expects a `(` after `function` but finds `new`

You have two options to fix this.

If `function new() end` is equivalent to `new = function () end`, `function () end` must resolve to a function value. So we can create a function value in-place:

```
table.insert(handler.class.someFrameName,
  function () print("Hello Stackoverflow!") end
)
```

I'll leave it up to you to impelement this in the string you want to load.

Another option is to define the function first. You can do this both in the string or in the scope of your `load` call.

```
function new() print("Hello Stackoverflow")
table.insert(handler.class.someFrameName, new)
```

Comment: While this is great and all, I seem to encounter a new problem when trying to achieve this approach. "table.insert(handler.class, [[function() print("Hello Stackoverflow!") end]], 1)" is throwing a new error ("uicode/hframe.lua:9: bad argument #2 to 'insert' (number expected, got string)") whenever I attempt to use it. Do you happen to know what I'm doing wrong trying to copy you?

Comment: you're providing a string as the optional third argument to table.insert. it expects a number. please ask a new question with updated code.

Comment: Why is the optional parameter in the middle!? WHAT IS THIS!? ... Thank you. PEBKAC on full display right there.

Comment: I don't know why they chose to have it in the middle. it already has been like that in Lua 4 maybe longer. it confuses me every time.

Answer (score 1):

Lua load() function returns nil and the error if it failed to compile code. Since the passed code is invalid, b is nil. Therefore a error is raised when you attempt to call it.

The reason the code is invalid is because when a function declaration is used as an expression, the function name must be omitted, e.g.

table.insert(sometable, function() … end)

Please note that most likely you don’t need to create code dynamically, the following will work:

table.insert(handler.class[framename], function() … end)

Comment: Hi! I like your answer, it helps me understand this a bit. I kind of knew load returns nil, which is why I used an assert. However, I was not aware that I didn't need the actual function name. May I please have clarification on how your final example works? I'm trying to put it into a table so I can call it like "handler.class.frame.new" if possible, although I'm flexible for other solutions.

Comment: Would you please clarify the whole [frame] business? I tried experimenting with it but it didn't seem to work as you implied.

Comment: @Missingno50 `foo.bar` is a shorthand for `foo["bar"]` in Lua. Please elaborate if I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: You seemed to have misunderstood my comment. Sort of. Specifying it like that throws up an error saying it's expecting a table and got nil. I'm creating a blank table named new, and then trying the command `table.insert(new["test"], "hello")`.